# Can Grid.Row be readjusted automatically on RowDefinition deletion?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I am manipulating a WPF Grid programmatically. I have a button to add a RowDefinition dynamically and one of of my grid columns contains a button to delete any RowDefinition in the grid.

When I click 'Remove' button I execute:

```
//Logic to remove all Cell contents first fort this Row
// ...
//Then Remove my RowDefinition
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Remove(MyRowDefinition);
```

That works fine, the problem I have is that that the Grid.Row AttachedProperty for the rest of the controls does not get re-adjusted automatically.

Is there a way to achieve this?

So if I have a:

```
<Label Name="lbl1" Grid.Row="0"/>
<Label Name="lbl2" Grid.Row="1"/>
<Label Name="lbl3" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

And I remove the second RowDefinition I would expect to end up with:

```
    <Label Name="lbl1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label Name="lbl3" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Not with what I'm getting:

```
    <Label Name="lbl1" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label Name="lbl3" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

But this is not the case. If there is no automatic way to do this then I'll have to code it myself.

Please Advise..

Here is how my app looks like:
[image: FormDesigner]

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add code to handle that yourself. UNLESS, you don't use a grid and you use a ListBox who's ListBoxItem Template is a Grid of 3 columns and one row.  One column is the red drag area, another the blue drag area, and the third for the button.  You only need one row because each ListBox item, is now going to represent a grid row.

First thing you have to do is ensure the collection storing the data in the grid you show above is an ObservableCollection.  Then bind it to the ListBox's ItemsSource.  I'm not sure what your data looks like, so ensure you handle all the bindings properly, if you have any.

Add a handler to the button's PreviewMouseUp.  Using PreviewMouseUp allows the ListBox to change the SelectedItem before the button's PreviewMouseUp is handled.  Then, have the corresponding handler remove the ListBox.SelectedItem from the collection bound to the ListBox.

Since, the collection being altered is an ObservableCollection bound to the ItemsSource, the ListBox will be notified to update its bindings and will handle all deletes for you.

Comment: That sounds like a practical way to do it @Josh, thanks for the suggestion. The thing is that this is a Form Designer and I would like the flexibility that a Grid provides in terms of Row and Column Span and things like that. I may eventually add functionality to add Columns too. I'm not sure if manipulating the template of a ListBox in code is worth it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it manually:

```
            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Remove(MyRowDefinition);
            myGrid.ReadjustRows(RemovedRowIndex);
```

I created a couple of Extension methods:

```
    public static  List<UIElement> GetGridCellChildren(this Grid grid, int row, int col)
    {
        return grid.Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(
                            x => Grid.GetRow(x) == row && Grid.GetColumn(x) == col).ToList();
    }

    public static void ReadjustRows(this Grid myGrid, int row)
    {
        if (row < myGrid.RowDefinitions.Count)
        {
            for (int i = row + 1; i <= myGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; j++)
                {
                    List<UIElement> children = myGrid.GetGridCellChildren(i, j);
                    foreach(UIElement uie in children)
                    {
                        Grid.SetRow(uie,i - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And if anyone ever needs it, here my extension method to remove all Contents of a given Grid Cell:

```
    public static void RemoveGridCellChildren(this Grid grid, int row, int col)
    {
        List<UIElement> GridCellChildren = GetGridCellChildren(grid, row, col);
        if (GridCellChildren != null && GridCellChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (UIElement uie in GridCellChildren)
            {
                grid.Children.Remove(uie);
            }
        }
    }
```